# Dataframe with column of type list: Append to selected rows

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I have two dataframes (created with code below) as

```
df1
       Fecha Vals
0 2001-01-01   []
1 2001-01-02   []
2 2001-01-03   []
3 2001-01-04   []
4 2001-01-05   []
5 2001-01-06   []
6 2001-01-07   []
7 2001-01-08   []
8 2001-01-09   []

df2
       Fecha  Vals
0 2001-01-01   0.0
1 2001-01-03   1.0
2 2001-01-05   2.0
3 2001-01-07   3.0
4 2001-01-09   4.0
```

I want to append values in `df2` to each corresponding row in `df1` to obtain

```
df1
       Fecha Vals
0 2001-01-01   [0.0]
1 2001-01-02   []
2 2001-01-03   [1.0]
3 2001-01-04   []
4 2001-01-05   [2.0]
5 2001-01-06   []
6 2001-01-07   [3.0]
7 2001-01-08   []
8 2001-01-09   [4.0]
```

I am close to finishing this with `for` loops, but for large dataframes my partial work already shows this becomes very slow.
I suspect there is a way to do it faster, without looping, but I couldn't so far get there.

As a first step, I could filter rows in `df1` with

```
df1['Fecha'].isin(df2['Fecha'].values)
```

**Notes**:

1. I will next need to repeat the operation with `df3`, etc., appending to other rows in `df1`.  I wouldn't want to remove duplicates. E.g., with `df3 = pd.DataFrame({'Fecha': ['2001-01-02', '2001-01-05', '2001-01-08'], 'Vals': [0.0, 1.0, 2.0]})`.
2. The uniform skipping in `df2` is a fabricated case.
3. After appending is complete, I would like to create one column for the averages of each row, and another column for the standard deviation.
4. Code to create my `df`s

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd
yy = 2001
date_list = ['{:4d}-{:02d}-{:02d}'.format(yy, mm, dd) for mm in range(1, 2) for dd in range(1, 10)]
fechas1 = [datetime.datetime.strptime(date_base, '%Y-%m-%d') for date_base in date_list]
nf1 = len(fechas1)
vals1 = [[] for _ in range(nf1)]
dic1 = { 'Fecha': fechas1, 'Vals': vals1 }
df1 = pd.DataFrame(dic1)
fechas2 = [datetime.datetime.strptime(date_list[idx], '%Y-%m-%d') for idx in range(0, nf1, 2)]
nf2 = len(fechas2)
vals2 = [float(idx) for idx in range(nf2)]
dic2 = { 'Fecha': fechas2, 'Vals': vals2 }
df2 = pd.DataFrame(dic2)
```

**Related**:

1. [Python intersection of 2 dataframes with list-type columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60583726/python-intersection-of-2-dataframes-with-list-type-columns)
2. [How to append list of values to a column of list in dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70341021/how-to-append-list-of-values-to-a-column-of-list-in-dataframe)
3. [Python appending a list to dataframe column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64734085/python-appending-a-list-to-dataframe-column)
4. [Pandas dataframe append to column containing list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63876119/pandas-dataframe-append-to-column-containing-list)
5. [Define a column type as 'list' in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37134622/define-a-column-type-as-list-in-pandas)
6. https://towardsdatascience.com/dealing-with-list-values-in-pandas-dataframes-a177e534f173

Comment: If you want lists stored in columns then you would be better with a dictionary of numpy arrays

Comment: Once you have an object type (as a list would be) in a column, you've destroyed all hope of having vectorized operations over it. Columns should contain scalars

Comment: @roganjosh - I wouldn't know the reason for that, would you mind clarifying?
Plus, I would lose the powerful resources around `pandas`, plus a lot of code that I wrote myself for this case.
So I would need very strong reasons to leave the intended path.

Comment: You have very few of the "powerful resources" of pandas because almost everything you want to then do with that column will have to drop down into python (with lambdas, for example). The benefit of pandas wrapping around numpy is for _vectorization_ of numerical operations, which can be pushed into optimised C code rather than sitting in python itself

Comment: At the moment, your `Vals` column is either empty or contains, at most, a single value. Why do you need a list in there at all? Can the list contain multiple values?

Comment: It's going to be a loop either way. The thing we're discussing, really, is whether that loop is running in C or in Python (often ~2 orders of magnitude slower)

Comment: Oki doki. Let me play with your toy code a bit and see if I can get something more akin to a pandas approach

Comment: @roganjosh - I removed some comments to reduce the clutter.

Comment: @roganjosh - The solution by Always Sunny works well, without looping (explicit at least).
I didn't make performance comparisons with other methods, but for my needs that works, better than explicit loops in similar applications I wrote (sorry, I cannot be more precise here).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `merge` instead of looping and a couple of `lambda` like this to update non-matched rows like this-

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Fecha': ['2001-01-01', '2001-01-02', '2001-01-03', '2001-01-04', '2001-01-05', '2001-01-06', '2001-01-07', '2001-01-08', '2001-01-09'], 'Vals': [[] for _ in range(9)]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Fecha': ['2001-01-01', '2001-01-03', '2001-01-05', '2001-01-07', '2001-01-09'], 'Vals': [0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]})

# Merge df1 and df2 on the 'Fecha' column, using an outer join
result = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='Fecha', how='left')
# Fill the null values in the 'Vals_y' column with an empty list
result['Vals_y'] = result['Vals_y'].apply(lambda x: [] if pd.isnull(x) else x)
# Append the values in the 'Vals_y' column to the 'Vals_x' column as a new element in a list for all rows where the 'Vals_y' column is not an empty list
result['Vals'] = result.apply(lambda row: row['Vals_x'] + [row['Vals_y']] if pd.notnull(row['Vals_y']) else row['Vals_x'], axis=1)

# drop unnecessary columns
result.drop(['Vals_x', 'Vals_y'], axis=1, inplace=True)
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
        Fecha   Vals
0  2001-01-01  [0.0]
1  2001-01-02     []
2  2001-01-03  [1.0]
3  2001-01-04     []
4  2001-01-05  [2.0]
5  2001-01-06     []
6  2001-01-07  [3.0]
7  2001-01-08     []
8  2001-01-09  [4.0]
```

Comment: This works well on including your lines inside a function, and applying it repeatedly. 
Plus: 
1. Performance is good. 
2. I made it work when `df1` and `df2` have other columns as well, not necessarily all the same.

Answer (score 1):

Using a simple loop:

```
s = df2.set_index('Fecha')['Vals']
idx = df1.loc[df1['Fecha'].isin(df2['Fecha'])].index

for i in idx:
    df1.loc[i, 'Vals'].append(s[df1.loc[i, 'Fecha']])
```

Updated `df1`:

```
        Fecha   Vals
0  2001-01-01  [0.0]
1  2001-01-02     []
2  2001-01-03  [1.0]
3  2001-01-04     []
4  2001-01-05  [2.0]
5  2001-01-06     []
6  2001-01-07  [3.0]
7  2001-01-08     []
8  2001-01-09  [4.0]
```

Comment: Works fine, with no sizable performance issues for my case.